# How to use multiple plugin in flutter?

Tags: flutter, plugins

I have two apps. I want to use them within a single application. I am able to switch between apps with BottomNavigationBar widget. But the problem starts with the application requesting the plugin. I can add one plugin to Pubspec.yaml file, how can I use the other plugin?

One of them use this,

```
plugin:
  platforms:
    android:
      package: net.ossrs.flutter_live
      pluginClass: FlutterLivePlugin
    ios:
      pluginClass: FlutterLivePlugin
```

Another one use this,

```
  plugin:
    platforms:
      android:
        package: com.app.rtmp_publisher
        pluginClass: RtmppublisherPlugin
      ios:
        pluginClass: RtmppublisherPlugin
```

How to combine these?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after checking [the plugin](http://github.com/nhancv/flutter_rtmp_publisher) i can see that Rtmp_publisher and other plugin are written raw inside specific platform..

The two are not flutter plugin. since you can a native code inside flutter so he write the libraries for specific platform.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need two apps? You may create only one app which has all plugins and you may use widgets inside it

Comment: Let me explain like this. The first application is for rtmp broadcasting.(https://github.com/nhancv/flutter_rtmp_publisher) The other application is for watching rtmp broadcast.(https://github.com/ossrs/flutter_live) And these applications use different plugins. Pubspec.yaml allows to use one.

Comment: Okay, I am sorry, still not able to understand why you are not able to install both packages together. Have you tried the following:

flutter pub add rtmp_publisher
flutter pub add flutter_live

Refer: https://pub.dev/packages/rtmp_publisher & https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_live